# How to add date and time under each post in guestbook in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

here is the code:

```
import cgi
import datetime
import wsgiref.handlers

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

class Greeting(db.Model):
  author = db.UserProperty()
  content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')

        greetings = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Greeting ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10")
        for greeting in greetings:

            if greeting.author:
                self.response.out.write('<b>%s</b> wrote:' % greeting.author.nickname())

            else:
                self.response.out.write('An anonymous person wrote:')
            self.response.out.write('<blockquote>%s</blockquote>' %
                                    cgi.escape(greeting.content))



        # Write the submission form and the footer of the page
        self.response.out.write("""
              <form action="/sign" method="post">
                <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
                <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
              </form>
            </body>
          </html>""")

class Guestbook(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    greeting = Greeting()

    if users.get_current_user():
      greeting.author = users.get_current_user()

    greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
    greeting.put()
    self.redirect('/')


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
  ('/sign', Guestbook)
], debug=True)


def main():
  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [strftime()](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) method on the datetime instance `greeting.date` with something like this:

```
for greeting in greetings:
 self.response.out.write(greeting.date.strftime('<b>posted:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S</b><br>'))
```

If you are having problem of indentation, copy and paste this code:

```
import cgi
import datetime
import wsgiref.handlers

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

class Greeting(db.Model):
  author = db.UserProperty()
  content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        greetings = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Greeting ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10")
        for greeting in greetings:
            self.response.out.write(greeting.date.strftime('<b>posted: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S</b><br>'))         
            if greeting.author:
                self.response.out.write('<b>%s</b> wrote:' % greeting.author.nickname())
            else:
                self.response.out.write('An anonymous person wrote:')
            self.response.out.write('<blockquote>%s</blockquote>' %
                                    cgi.escape(greeting.content))
        # Write the submission form and the footer of the page
        self.response.out.write("""
              <form action="/sign" method="post">
                <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
                <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
              </form>
            </body>
          </html>""")

class Guestbook(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    greeting = Greeting()
    if users.get_current_user():
      greeting.author = users.get_current_user()
    greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
    greeting.put()
    self.redirect('/')


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
  ('/sign', Guestbook)
], debug=True)


def main():
  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: weeell thanks for yor answer but im a tottaly newbie :( every time i add something like this i get

File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\demos\guestbook\guestbook.py", line 45
    if greeting.author:
                      ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: mmm...now im getting 
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\demos\gb\guestbook.py", line 36, in get
    self.response.out.write(greeting.date.strftime('<b>posted: %d, %h %Y </b><br>'))
ValueError: Invalid format string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
greetings = Greeting.all().order('date')
for greeting in greetings.fetch(10):
  self.response.out.write(greeting.date.strftime('<b>posted: %d, %b %Y </b><br>'))
```

Hope this works...