# Google app engine error invalid string format

Tags: google-app-engine

Hello guys i have a little problem i get an error:

```
"File "C:\Users\kokki\Desktop\gb1\main.py", line 36, in get
self.response.out.write(greeting.date.strftime('<b>posted: %d, %h %Y </b><br>'))
ValueError: Invalid format string"
```

can anyone help? heres the code:

```
import cgi
import datetime
import wsgiref.handlers

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

class Greeting(db.Model):
  author = db.UserProperty()
  content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        greetings = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Greeting ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10")
        for greeting in greetings:
            self.response.out.write(greeting.date.strftime('<b>posted: %d, %h %Y </b><br>'))         
            if greeting.author:
                self.response.out.write('<b>%s</b> wrote:' % greeting.author.nickname())
            else:
                self.response.out.write('An anonymous person wrote:')
            self.response.out.write('<blockquote>%s</blockquote>' %
                                    cgi.escape(greeting.content))
        # Write the submission form and the footer of the page
        self.response.out.write("""
              <form action="/sign" method="post">
                <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
                <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
              </form>
            </body>
          </html>""")

class Guestbook(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    greeting = Greeting()
    if users.get_current_user():
      greeting.author = users.get_current_user()
    greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
    greeting.put()
    self.redirect('/')


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
  ('/sign', Guestbook)
], debug=True)


def main():
  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Which line raises the error? Please post the complete stacktrace. Also, next time indent the code with 4 spaces in order to format it correctly.

Comment: "[Question already been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5531137/687692)"
Try this, Hope this will help: [Click Here for the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531137/how-to-add-date-and-time-under-each-post-in-guestbook-in-google-app-engine/5549944#5549944)

Comment: This question appears to be the same as [your question from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531137/how-to-add-date-and-time-under-each-post-in-guestbook-in-google-app-engine). Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%h` is an invalid placeholder for `strftime`. See the valid format specifiers at [the `time` module docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-time.html) (Python 2.5.2 docs).